# stylegan2 tensorflow without gpu

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to run the command in docker/mac. but i need to run it on cpu only. not gpu.
How can I achieve this?

```
python run_generator.py generate-images --network=gdrive:networks/stylegan2-ffhq-config-f.pkl \--seeds=66,230,389,1518 --truncation-psi=1.0
```

> Local submit - run_dir: results/00001-generate-images
> dnnlib: Running run_generator.generate_images() on localhost...
> Loading networks from "gdrive:networks/stylegan2-ffhq-config-f.pkl"...
> Setting up TensorFlow plugin "fused_bias_act.cu": Preprocessing... Failed!
> File "/home/stylegan2/dnnlib/tflib/custom_ops.py", line 52, in _get_cuda_gpu_arch_string
> raise RuntimeError('No GPU devices found')
> RuntimeError: No GPU devices found

https://github.com/NVlabs/stylegan2/blob/master/README.md#using-pre-trained-networks

running pretrained

Comment: Where does that command come from?

Comment: https://github.com/NVlabs/stylegan2/blob/master/README.md#using-pre-trained-networks

Comment: Well, the requirements for the project says "One or more high-end NVIDIA GPUs, NVIDIA drivers, CUDA 10.0 toolkit and cuDNN 7.5." Sounds like you're on your own to make it run without GPU.